# How to update one item without affecting other arguments?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update only one thing in the database, how to do it?

Suppose I want to update imgUrl, how to update only it without affecting other arguments?

```js
 updateDataProjects = (id, companyName, imgUrl, userOrderCollection) => {
  firebase.firestore()
  .collection("projects")
  .doc(id)
  .set({
    companyName: companyName,
    imgUrl: imgUrl,
    userOrderCollection: userOrderCollection
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have to access the update function like this:

```js
updateDataProjects(id, companyName, imgUrl, userOrderCollection);
```

And how to apply like that?

```js
updateDataProjects(...argements, imgUrl);
```

Comment: Your question is not that clear, you want to update imgUrl but whats the json structure? do you want to update value of an object's key only or what else?
Please provide more details

Comment: I mean, my update function takes more than one argument, and what if I need to update only one argument?

Comment: If you have a function which take more than one argument, and you want to update only one argument you can use the default values for the arguments. for example.
here second argument is optional
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a * b;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments of function `updateDataProjects` as an object. `updateDataProjects({ id, companyName, imgUrl, userOrderCollection });`
And use as `updateDataProjects({ imgUrl });`

Answer (score 0):

Add `{merge: true}` as the second argument to `set` and it will only update the provided fields.

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collection("projects")
  .doc(id)
  .set({
    imgUrl: imgUrl,
  }, {merge: true})
}
```

More on this in the docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

If you only want to update one item then just pass in one item. So `updateDataProjects(,, imgUrl)`.  But you have to be aware to pass it in as the third argument, so after two commas.

A better solution would be to transform the parameters into a single object so you don't have to worry about the order of arguments. So the call becomes`updateDataProjects({id, companyName, imgUrl, userOrderCollection})`. Then you can destructure the same prop in your function like so `const updateDataProjects = ({id, companyName, imgUrl, userOrderCollection}) => {...}`. If you just want one field only pass one in `updateDataProjects({imgUrl})` and the order no longer matters.